# What is that component?

Tags: components

Hello I've got this Component with an arduino pack and I want to know what it is.

[image]

It only has one label on it "HDX" I googled it but didn't find any thing
it has also one short golden leg and a normal leg 
I can hear something inside it moving if i tilt or shake the component

Can anyone please tell me what is that component and how it works?

Comment: I would say its wood. Plywood maybe? Not sure from the angle, you can hardly see the side. Looks dirty and not well lit, might be birch

Comment: Thanks for your effort captain @PlasmaHH you're so funny :)

Comment: Why does this have 2 down votes? Its good question in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a vibration switch according to this article [here](https://galenrhodes.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/identifying-the-odd-electronic-component/).

Answer (score 1):

It is a [Vibration switch](http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/HDX-Vibration-Sensor-Vibration-Switch/205970_631936498.html). Below image shows the internal construction.

[image]

Shaking it should break the connection between the ends momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment that you can "can hear something inside it moving if i tilt or shake" it indicates that it is probably a rolling-ball tilt/movement sensor.

If you wire it into a circuit with an LED, or even just attach it to a continuity tester you should find that such movement makes/breaks the circuit.

Comment: Thanks you Chris I just realized that it is a vibration switch.